# IOS app has bugs that don't show up in emulator or Mac version

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, testflight, appstore-approval

I just got into Flutter development last year, so far it's going good.
Last week I tried to upload a .ipa file to App Store Connect for TestFlight.
I got the following feedback from Apple:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app.
> Specifically, we were unable to proceed beyond the launch screen.
> Please review the details below and complete the next steps.
> Review device details:
> Device type: iPhone 13 mini and iPad Air (5th generation)
> OS version: iOS 17.4

This bug doesn't show up in the 17.4 emulator or in the debug build I'm running on Mac.
It doesn't show up in the Android build either (Galaxy S22+).
I do not have access to an iPhone or iPad to install the app on.
Why is this and how do I fix this bug without it showing up in the emulator or Mac version?

I'm running Android Studio 2023.2.1, Xcode 15.3, iOS 17.4 (Emulator), Flutter 3.9 and Dart 3.3.

Comment: Having access to a real iOS device is pretty important if you want to release an iOS app. The simulator isn't the same as a real device. You need to test a TestFlight build on a real device. Test when the device has no network connection. Test on a pure ipv6 network.

Comment: @Paulw11 The app is in a very early build, I'll buy an iOS device when the release comes closer. But in the meantime, the emulator should be sufficient, the fact that it isn't is mind-blowing to me. I'm not buying an iOS device for this side project in this stage of the project...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single "oh, you need to do x to fix your problem" answer. The simulator is not a real device. Its main purpose is to help you with layout on different device families. It does not have the same restrictions as a real device (cpu performance, file system sandbox restrictions etc). A debug build is not a release build. You have a problems that is only showing up in a release build on a real device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Firebase Crashlytics to your project. With this tool you can catch all type of errors and upload it to Firebase.

[Firebase Crashlytics docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics?hl=es-419)